# zsh autocomplete for diff: do not offer to complete same file repeatedly

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have two files:

```
$ ls
file1  file2
```

and I want to compare them with `diff`. When I type `diff file1 f', the completion system offers me both files:

```
diff file1 file<TAB>
file1  file2
```

is it possible to tell the completion system, that if `file1` is already used, it should not be offered for completion again?

Perhaps there is some easy way to do it using the `zstyle` `completion` syntax?

```
zstyle ':completion:*'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on the [`ignore-line`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-ignore_002dline_002c-completion-style) style:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:diff:argument-*:*' ignore-line true
```

Alternatively, change the completion function:

```
_diff () {
    local ignore
    ignore=($words[2,$#words])
        _diff_options "$words[1]" ':original file:_files -F ignore' ':new file:_files -F ignore'  
}
```

(This approach is a simplification of what [`_rm`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Unix/Command/_rm) does.)

Both methods take care of the common case that `diff bar baTab` will offer `baz` for completion but not `bar`. Neither method takes care of all edge cases, for example `diff bar ./baTab` offers `./bar` for completion even though that's the same file as `bar`. The first method has the downside of not offering to complete a file called `diff`, because the `ignore-line` style ignores every word including the command name.

Comment: that is perfect